# show console tab instead of drawer on errors in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is a minor annoyance but I can't seem to find any solution.

I don't really like the console "drawer" (the console you see when you hit "Esc") and prefer to use the tab/page as I don't have a lot of space to devote to the developer tools.  When you load a page with errors or warnings there's little icons on the far right that indicate counts of each, but when you click on that it always opens the "drawer" version of the console instead of the tab/page version.  Is there any way to change this?  (I vaguely recall that it used to always open the tab/page version before)

Comment: god.. this is the most annoying thing in chrome's console

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to customize such behavior. One thing you could do to slightly speed up things is to re-arrange panels in DevTools so that it is easier for you to get into "Console".

Comment: I remembered the console being at the far right before too so I dragged it over there.  I just have to remember to click it instead of the error icons.